# How I play video with suggested player inside social app?

Tags: javascript, html

My app having JW player and I am sharing one video (embedded code or link) on Facebook so Facebook will play that video with JW player.

I shared one video using JM player, video posted successfully on Facebook but not working.

Please suggest me how should I do this?

We have implemented this with the following reference

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1409823-social-sharing-overlay

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("container").setup({
    file: "/uploads/video.mp4",
    sharing: {
      code: encodeURI("<iframe src='http://example.com/embed/12345.html' />"),
      link: "http://example.com/page/12345/"
   }
 });
</script>

  jwplayer("container").setup({
    playlist: [{ 
       file: "/videos/12345.mp4",
       mediaid: "12345"
    },{
       file: "/videos/67890.mp4",
       mediaid: "67890"
    }],
    sharing: {
      code: encodeURI("<iframe src='http://example.com/embed/MEDIAID.html' />"),
      link: "http://example.com/page/MEDIAID/"
   }
 });
```

It will share link on social media, but not able to play video with custom player.

Basically need to create a custom player like YouTube.